# Apache Won't Start after Adding SSL Certificates

Tags: apache, ssl, centos

Hello so here is the problem

I have generated CSR on CentOS and purchased SSL on Comodo.

I have added following lines to ssl.conf

```
ServerName mydomain.com 
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mydomain.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mydomain.crt
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mydomainCA.crt
```

and following lines to httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName thedomain.com
        Redirect "/" "https://thedomain.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

After this when I do **systemctl restart httpd** it gives me following error:

> ```
> Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl
> ```
>
> -xe" for details.
>
> and when I check **journalctl -xe** for details this is what it reads:
>
> -- Subject: Unit httpd.service has finished start-up
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>
> ### -- Unit httpd.service has finished starting up.
>
> -- The start-up result is done. Nov 24 18:36:01 MyWay polkitd[568]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:6639:684652621
>   (system bus name :1.4409, object path
>   /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale e Nov 24
>   18:36:04 MyWay sshd[6652]: Invalid user oracle from 80.241.211.237
>   port 54600 Nov 24 18:36:04 MyWay sshd[6652]: input_userauth_request:
>   invalid user oracle [preauth] Nov 24 18:36:04 MyWay sshd[6652]:
>   pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown Nov 24 18:36:04 MyWay
>   sshd[6652]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname=
>   uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=vmi306916.contaboserver.net Nov 24
>   18:36:06 MyWay sshd[6652]: Failed password for invalid user oracle
>   from 80.241.211.237 port 54600 ssh2 Nov 24 18:36:06 MyWay sshd[6652]:
>   Received disconnect from 80.241.211.237 port 54600:11: Normal
>   Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth] Nov 24 18:36:06 MyWay
>   sshd[6652]: Disconnected from 80.241.211.237 port 54600 [preauth] Nov
>   24 18:36:16 MyWay sshd[6651]: Received disconnect from 112.85.42.94
>   port 31545:11:  [preauth] Nov 24 18:36:16 MyWay sshd[6651]:
>   Disconnected from 112.85.42.94 port 31545 [preauth] Nov 24 18:36:18
>   MyWay polkitd[568]: Registered Authentication Agent for
>   unix-process:6655:684654361 (system bus name :1.4410
>   [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path
>   /org/freedes Nov 24 18:36:18 MyWay systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache
>   HTTP Server...
>   -- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun shutting down
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>
> -- Unit httpd.service has begun shutting down. Nov 24 18:36:19 MyWay systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
>   -- Subject: Unit httpd.service has finished shutting down
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>
> -- Unit httpd.service has finished shutting down. Nov 24 18:36:19 MyWay systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
>   -- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>
> -- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up. Nov 24 18:36:19 MyWay systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited,
>   status=1/FAILURE Nov 24 18:36:19 MyWay kill[6667]: kill: cannot find
>   process "" Nov 24 18:36:19 MyWay systemd[1]: httpd.service: control
>   process exited, code=exited status=1 Nov 24 18:36:19 MyWay systemd[1]:
>   Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
>   -- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>
> ### -- Unit httpd.service has failed.
>
> -- The result is failed. Nov 24 18:36:19 MyWay systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state. Nov 24 18:36:19 MyWay systemd[1]:
>   httpd.service failed. Nov 24 18:36:19 MyWay polkitd[568]: Unregistered
>   Authentication Agent for unix-process:6655:684654361 (system bus name
>   :1.4410, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent,
>   locale e [

So I have checked lot os solutions but this problems still exists, please note that when I comment out all changes in httpd.conf and ssl.conf apache starts working back normally.

Thanks all in advance

Comment: Have a look at the error log for apache (see the apache configuration where this file can be found). My guess is that one of the files you've given in the configuration either does not exist or has the wrong type (i.e. switched key and cert) or encoding (PEM is expected, maybe you've used DER).

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Renaming file to PEM helped the case, besides this I came across some other issues that were causing error ( looking ata apache logs helped me to solv them )

1. Memory for apache was full so I had to increase it.
2. I had duplicated SSLCertificateKeyFile in the ssl.conf file and I commented out the default file link.